# Gvim delete buffer when close tab

Tags: vim

How to delete buffer when after right click on tab I choose `close`?

Comment: why do you want to delete the buffer? If you really want, do `:bdel`, this will also close the tab.

Comment: Shame on me, old habit, mouse and use of right click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
:set nohidden
```

If this works, add `set nohidden` to your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: I just `:set nohidden` and NO, it does not delete the buffer

Comment: @kfl62 It should not. It just unloads buffer when it is abandoned, thus preventing it from consuming memory.